# Read image file

Tags: python, windows, binary, type-conversion

I have this picture of white and black squares. Each square represents a 0-Black and 1-White. Is there a way to scan the image from left to right and write the binary output to a .txt file? I need to do it in python.
Thank you
[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbRQS.png)

Comment: Look into using an image processing library to convert the image to 2-D array (of pixels), and use that to construct the binary string based off the pixel value. [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/index.html) should be able to do this with no problems.

Comment: The provided image is 1920x1080 pixels. Do you need matrix of 1920x1080 or the actual matrix of the QR size?

Comment: How will the text file look? One line per image line? Commas between values?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Just one long line

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def image_to_txt(image_path, output_file):
    # Open the image
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    
    # Convert the image to grayscale
    image = image.convert("L")
    
    # Convert the image to a NumPy array
    image_array = np.array(image)
    
    # Write the NumPy array to a text file
    with open(output_file, "w") as file:
        np.savetxt(file, image_array, fmt='%d')

# Replace 'input_image.png' with your image file and 'output.txt' with the desired output file name
image_to_txt('input_image.png', 'output.txt')
```

Comment: Straight out from chatgpt?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

# Open image and ensure in mode "1"
filename = sys.argv[1]
im = Image.open(filename).convert('1')

# Scale down by a factor of 5 so one block = 1 pixel
im = ImageOps.scale(im, 1/5.0, resample = Image.Resampling.NEAREST)

[ print(f'{int(p/255)}', end='') for p in im.getdata()]
```

Comment: in the image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbRQS.png) the first 10 squares are white and the next one is black then two white, three black and so on. In the output i see the numbers in the correct order, but I get more numbers than the number of squares. Here is the numbers for the first 16 squares (000000000000011111000001111111111) and in this case I need (0000000000100111). I hope you understand this reply, because English is not my native language

Comment: The image is 1920x1080 and my script produces exactly 2,073,600 (1920*1080) digits. The first 50 are white the next 5 are black, so it looks like you are using an image that is scaled down ion size by a factor of 5 for some reason. Please check the dimensions of your image.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding. "The first 50 are white..." - Do you mean pixels? Because I am not looking for the number of pixels, but the number of squares. These next 5 black pixels form one square (5x5)

Comment: I added an extra line to scale the image down by a factor of 5 in each direction so pixels now correspond to blocks.

Comment: How are you getting on with this answer?

Comment: Thank you man. You really helped me. And sorry for the late answer. Thank you